# Not working url www without font awesome

Tags: font-awesome

Currently I use font awesome well on the path `http: //` but it does not work on the url `WWW`.

The problem is due to the domain config URL `WWW`?

Answer (score 0):

When you type in www, your browser may instead be using the HTTPS protocol, and font-awesome will not load because your browser is refusing to GET the font-awesome file through HTTP.

If your link is HTTP only, as in:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Then it may only work when you force it by going to your website through HTTP.

You can try to change it to //...:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

This allows both HTTP and HTTPS protocols.